# Maven Release Plugin: Permission denied (publickey) Github

Tags: maven, github, ssh-keys, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to deploy my Maven project which is hosted on Github. I have generated and added my public key to Github, and also I think I have filled the `pom.xml` with all the required properties:

```
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>MIT License</name>
        <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Hristo Vrigazov</name>
        <email>hvrigazov@gmail.com</email>
        <organization>Hribol</organization>
        <organizationUrl>https://github.com/hristo-vrigazov</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
</developers>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/hristo-vrigazov/bromium.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git://github.com/hristo-vrigazov/bromium.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/hristo-vrigazov/bromium</url>
    <tag>com.hribol.bromium.dsl.parent-1.0.0</tag>
</scm>
```

I am trying to release as follows:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
ssh-add -l
mvn release:prepare release:perform -B -e | tee maven-central-deploy.log
```

However, I keep getting this message from Maven, indicating that there is a problem with my SSH key:

```
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:299)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:247)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 20 more
Caused by: 
org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.ReleaseScmCommandException: Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What could be the reason? I was able to deploy the snapshots to Nexus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the wrong [protocol (the "git" one)](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol) in your URL:

```
<connection>scm:git:git://github.com/hristo-vrigazov/bromium.git</connection>
```

It should be using ssh:

```
<connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/hristo-vrigazov/bromium.git</connection>
```

or

```
<connection>scm:git:git@github.com:hristo-vrigazov/bromium.git</connection>
```

(same for `developerConnection`)
Only then, your ssh key would be used.

Comment: I found that error after upgrading one of Java dependency and problem has gone after applying that fix

Answer (score -2):

Make sure if you are using profiles, to specify -P in the arguments of the mvn release:command